# Joining on different records with union

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have an issue I cannot get around despite everything I tried.
I am creating a table with multiple join and uniting the tables that are pulled from 2 different DB's some of the records overlap between the two DB's and I have the following issue:
Table 1

```
+------+--------+-------+------+
| Col1 |  Col2  | Col3  | Algo |
+------+--------+-------+------+
|    1 | jOB1   | Test1 | NULL |
|    1 |  JOB2  | Test2 | NULL |
|    1 |  JOB3  | Test3 | Null |
+------+--------+-------+------+
```

Table 2:

```
+------+--------+-------+-------+
| Col1 |  Col2  | Col3  | Algo  |
+------+--------+-------+-------+
|    1 | jOB1   | Test1 | NULL  |
|    1 |  JOB2  | Test2 | NULL  |
|    1 |  JOB3  | Test3 | ARFTU |
+------+--------+-------+-------+
```

UNION

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+
| Col1 | Col2  | Col3  | Algo  |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
|    1 | jOB1  | Test1 | NULL  |
|    1 | JOB2  | Test2 | NULL  |
|    1 | JOB3  | Test3 | NULL  |
|    1 | JOB3  | Test3 | ARFTU |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

How do I eliminate the row with the NULL value in the final table? if another
row exists with identical Col1,Col2,Col3 columns?

Thank in advance!!!

Editing my my end result to make this more clear:
The table I would like to get in the end is table 2, i.e. if the 'Algo' value doesn't exist keep the row with null. If 'Algo' value does exist remove the NULL record and only keep the populated records:

```
+------+--------+-------+-------+
| Col1 |  Col2  | Col3  | Algo  |
+------+--------+-------+-------+
|    1 | jOB1   | Test1 | NULL  |
|    1 |  JOB2  | Test2 | NULL  |
|    1 |  JOB3  | Test3 | ARFTU |
+------+--------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Can you please provide what the correct result should be?  It's not very clear if you want all `NULL`s or only JOB3 with `NULL` to be eliminated.

Comment: I want to eliminate Job3 with NULL @Gordon Linoff answer is the one i was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use aggregation?

```
select col1, col2, col3, max(algo) as algo
from ((select col1, col2, col3, algo from t1) union all
      (select col1, col2, col3, algo from t2)
     ) tt
group by col1, col2, col3;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! that worked! I was hoping for something a little more elegant (my actual table has over 30 columns) but still! thank you!!

Comment: @A.Lot Please mark it as correct then to close this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on

```
select * from (
  select * from t1 where algo is not null
  union
  select * from t2 where algo is not null)
t
```

i try to eliminate each selection table first. well, if you have same col1,2,3 value and algo has value both, it will be fetched.
if algo has same value then will merge, else if algo has different value, it will be fetch both.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the ones that should be removed (inter table below) and then
remove them from the result:

```
with both as (select * from t1 union select * from t2),
--- col1,col2,col3 for which one is null and the other is not
     inter as ((select col1, col2, col3 from t1 where algo is null 
               intersect
               select col1, col2, col3 from t2 where algo is not null) 
               UNION
               (select col1, col2, col3 from t1 where algo is not null 
               intersect
               select col1, col2, col3 from t2 where algo is null
select * from both
  except
-- remove those that are in the intersection but also have null
select * from 
    (select * from both where algo is null)  as temp2
    natural join inter;
```